# how to fix magento runs in the wrong js path

Tags: magento2, javascript

I'm having a problem: my js line is correct but when running, Magento runs incorrectly. Does anyone know how to fix it?

Comment: Can you put the code here or explain the problem a bit more, so that someone can understand better and reply?

Comment: I am having problems with the error report.CRITICAL: Unable to resolve the source file for 'frontend/Pearl/weltpixel_custom/en_US/weltpixel_ga4_gtm.js' [] [] in the above error message the path is missing